# How to Get the Sum of Elements in Array without including Elements less than 80

Tags: arrays, c

I am working with this code that computes the sum of array when I got an idea how to exclude the elements of array that are below 80.

the statement ( if (a[x] < 80) ) is not working

Below is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define p printf

main()
{
clrscr();
int a[10], x, sum=0;
p("\nEnter 10 numbers greater than 80: ");
for(x=0; x<10; x++)
    scanf("%d", &a[x]);

for(x=0; x<10; x++)
    sum=sum+a[x];
    p("The sum is %d", sum);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is `if (a[x] < 80)` in your code?

Comment: What statement ( if (a[x] < 80) )??

Comment: I remove it since its no use

Comment: You also seem to assume that code blocks in C are delimited by indentation. They are not. Use `{}`

Comment: I'm guessing your `if` statement "doesn't work" because of your lack of appropriately defined scope blocks using `{ }`, please edit your question and provide a [mre]. `if` statements _do_ work, you're using it incorrectly in a way that's impossible to definitively discern since your code doesn't show your attempt at using it.

Comment: It should be `if (a[x] >= 80)`

Comment: And `main` should return `int` explicitly. Implicit `int` return type has been removed with `C11` standard.

Comment: I don't know how to say this delicately, but *please* don't use things like `#define p printf`.  I realize we call `printf` a lot in C programs, but trust me, trying to save 5 keystrokes per call is not something to strive for, and does not improve your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your code into this:

```
for(x=0; x<10; x++){
    if( a[x] > 80){
        sum=sum+a[x];
    }
}
printf("The sum is %d", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have, as pseudocode,

```
for(each element in the array)
    add it into 'sum'
```

What you want is

```
for(each element in the array)
    if(it's greater than 80)
        add it into 'sum'
```

So now you just need the right C syntax to do this.  There's a wrong way and a right way to go about it.

Wrong way: type in random guesses, perhaps informed by your knowledge of some programming language other than C, hoping for something that will work.

Right way: read the first one or two chapters of your introductory C textbook or tutorial carefully.  All the information you'll need is, I guarantee it, in there.  It will take you a few hours to read, but that'll be much, much less time (and frustration!) than you'll spend trying to learn C by trial and error.  C is *not* a language to learn by trial and error!